# Angular 6 how to define two url HTTP request 404 not found

Tags: angular

I work with Angular 6 and I want to define two url.

I define two url in the following  component

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Model } from "./repository.model";
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientJsonpModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { RestDataSourceChart, REST_URL_CHART } from "./rest.datasource.chart";
import { RestDataSource, REST_URL } from "./rest.datasource";

@NgModule({ 
    imports: [HttpClientModule, HttpClientJsonpModule],
    providers: [Model,  RestDataSourceChart, RestDataSource,
        { provide: REST_URL, useValue: `http://${location.hostname}:3500/products`},
        { provide: REST_URL_CHART, useValue: `http://${location.hostname}:3500/shoppingchart`}]
})
export class ModelModule { }
```

I do a GET request to http://${location.hostname}:3500/shoppingchart

```
import { Injectable, Inject, InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { Product } from "./product.model";
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";


    export const REST_URL_CHART = new InjectionToken("rest_url");

    @Injectable()
    export class RestDataSourceChart {
        constructor(private http: HttpClient,

            @Inject(REST_URL_CHART) private urlChart: string) { }

        getData(): Observable<Product[]> {
            return this.sendRequest<Product[]>("GET", this.urlChart);
        }
```

In the console I see the error message 404

```
GET /shoppingchart 404 0.182 ms - 2


rest datasource.chart getData
GET http://localhost:3500/shoppingchart 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I define this url http://localhost:3500/shoppingchart?

Comment: Is http://localhost:3500/shoppingchart running as a local server?

Comment: Yes, I want to run http://localhost:3500/shoppingchart in my host

Comment: Then you have a different problem to solve:" how to set up a node.js server locally"? Google it, you'll find plenty of information about it.

Comment: To run my application I executed  npm run json and after  ng server.  It finds the url http://${location.hostname}:3500/products but it doesn't find http://${location.hostname}:3500/shoppingchart`

Comment: 404 means shoppingchart url not available on you server side endpoint so please check it in postman is working or not